# Check if given key equals the given value

Tags: php, arrays

Hello again Stackoverflow!

```
<?php
    $array();
    $array['key1'] = 'value1';
    $array['key2'] = 'value2'
?>
```

I have an array set up like this. And the user inputs for example "key1" and "value1". How do I check if it's from the same row?

Comment: what row, can you elaborate on it?

Comment: if ($array[$key] == $value) ?

Comment: Also add **semicolon** in the fourth line

Comment: as a future visitor this question helped me

Answer (score 6):

You could try with something like this:

```
if ($array[$key1] == $value) {
   // we have a match
}
```

Also you really don't need 3 rows to create an array. This is completely sufficient:

```
$array = array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2');
```

Comment: Wow, I feel quite dumb now.

Comment: @Thew You have a decent reputation, you shouldn't be asking questions like these :P

Comment: Let's just say I've been inactive for quite some time.

Comment: Isn't SO kind of like riding a bike? I mean, it's pretty hard to "forget" that your aren't supposed to ask garbage questions with zero research effort.

Comment: rdlowrey Wow, not trying to be rude or anything.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if key and value belongs to same row using foreach loop

E.g.

```
      foreach($array as $key=>$value)
      {

      }
```

In each  iteration you will get key-value pair so you can easily identify the relationship between key and value within array variable.